# check for existence and active state in django filter

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-orm, django-filter

Is there a way to do a combined filter to see if an object exists and if it exists whether it is active or not?

Trying to find out whether a like model instance exists for a user or not, and whether the like is active or not.

I'm using this to change the display of initial css. If the user has liked it then it will display say a green like button or something to signify this. The ajax then updates the counter / toggles css class, view creates a like or toggles the state of an existing like. Just wondering if there's a neater way to check this condition.

Current filtering / method:

```
likes = article.articlelike_set.filter(is_active=1)
users_like = likes.filter(user=request.user)
user_liked_article = users_like[0].is_active if users_like.exists() else False
```

like / article model relation in like app:

```
class BaseLike(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:

        abstract = True

class ArticleLike(BaseLike, models.Model):

    article = models.ForeignKey('article.Article')
    ....
```

article model:

```
class ArticleBaseFields(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=1)

    class Meta:

        abstract = True

class Article(ArticleBaseFields,models.Model):

    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('userprofiles.ArticlePublisher', related_name="publisher") 
    #Publisher is a profile with a OneToOneField to auth.models User model
    ...
```

Comment: Please provide more context e.g. fields on different models such as `Article`, `Likes`, `Users` and how they are interlinked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already filtering on `is_active=1`, you don't need to check later for `users_like[0].is_active` because at this time you only have all the likes which are active.

The alternative way would be to get all the likes for the user first (*which should ideally be 1 or 0*)

```
user_likes = article.articlelike_set.filter(user=request.user)
```

now, first you can check if an like for the user exists or not:

```
user_likes.exists() # user has liked an article
```

or, if an active like for an user exists or not:

```
user_likes.filter(is_active=1).exists() # user has liked an article and it is active
```

---

On a completely different note, if you use [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) your code would look more beautiful:

```
 article = models.ForeignKey('article.Article', related_name='likes')

 # to filter on likes
 article.likes.filter(...)
```